# mosquitto_pub: error while loading shared libraries: libmosquitto.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, mqtt, mosquitto, fedora-21

I encountered this problem when I compiled mosquitto on my Fedora 21 box from source.

> mosquitto_pub: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libmosquitto.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

The clients (i.e mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub) keep throwing that error even with reinstallation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this problem with sysmlinks

```
$vi /etc/ld.so.conf
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
include /usr/local/lib
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib
$/sbin/ldconfig
$ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmosquitto.so.1 /usr/lib/libmosquitto.so.1
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense, if your libraries are in /usr/local/mosquitto/lib, then the symlinks you have created would make no difference. If the libraries are in /usr/local/lib then just running ldconfig would update the linker cache, no need to modify ld.so.conf.

Comment: Yes, you're right about /usr/local/mosquitto/lib. I've changed it to /usr/local/lib. About just running 'ldconfig' to update the linker cache, I did try that to no avail before having this somewhat 'dirty' solution.

Comment: You're right, I'm suprised that /usr/local/lib isn't in the default settings for Fedora.

Comment: this solution worked for installing mosquitto on amazon linux 2

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have installed the libraries to `/usr/local/lib`, which is the default, the correct answer is to run `/sbin/ldconfig` as root/sudo.

On some systems you will need to add `/usr/local/lib` to the paths that ld caches, e.g.

```
echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the accepted answer.  Seems better all around and worked for me

Answer (score 5):

This indicates that the linker does not know where to find the library. Just run `sudo /sbin/ldconfig` to update the linker cache of libraries. This is not something that is unique to mosquitto.

Answer (score 0):

I installed mosquitto from source on Ubuntu 20.04. So, the `libmosquitto.so.1` was in the same directory as the source files. I copied it to `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`folder. Then running the `mosquitto_sub` worked!